# Find input submit element by multiple class values in Splinter?

Tags: python, dom, web-scraping, screen-scraping, splinter

I would like to find such element:

```
<input type="submit" value="login" class="button button-line navy" onclick="...">
```

I'm using such method but it finds nothing:

`browser.find_by_css('.button .button-line .navy').first().click()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
browser.find_by_css('.button.button-line.navy').first().click()
```

As the `CSS` classes are on the same element, the selector must be without space `.button.button-line.navy`.

If there is space in between it will start looking at the child nodes. That's why you were not getting any matches.